# WPF datagrid with datepicker in cell blocks the enter key

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datepicker, textblock

I have a Datepicker/Textblock in a Datagrid. I can select, and enter the date, how ever, the enter key or click event does not enter the date into the datagrid. If i click outside the datagrid, it accepts the date values. I am confused as to what's going on. Any ideas why this would happen? What is the solution?

Here's, the code, seems quite straightforward.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgTestingDates"  ItemsSource="{Binding TestingDates}"  CanUserAddRows="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ColumnWidth="*" Margin="21,300,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="165" Width="245" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Time,UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=Time,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Yes this is default WPF behavior, as it only exits edit mode when you tab out.  That's the root cause, it's still in edit mode.  You can bypass this by setting up an event handler in the control you want and then ending the edit mode of the cell you are in.

Comment: thanks @JohnPeters ! I wanted to avoid adding a handler just to get out of edit mode, but I guess I have no choice. I am trying to adhere to MVVM design and have minimal code behind the View.

Comment: Yes, but don't worry about changing state in Code Behind as it still is ok when using MVVM.  For example a key down of "enter" could simply end the edit mode.  This can be done with "beahviors" too but to me PreviewKeyDown is just too simple.

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem....

```
public class CustomDatePicker : DatePicker
{
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        if (Template != null)
        {
            var box = (TextBox)Template.FindName("PART_TextBox", this);
            box.AddHandler(KeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler(OnTextBoxKeyDown), true);
        }
    }

    private void OnTextBoxKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            // The DatePicker set this as handled, which breaks the DataGrid commit model.
            e.Handled = false;
        }
    }
}
```