# WPF DatePicker Date-Validation after Enter key pressed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker, .net-4.7.2

I have set an InputBinding in a WPF application, along with a DatePicker and a TextBox.

When I press the Enter key while the focus is not on the DatePicker, my KeyBinding Event is triggered.

When the focus is on the DatePicker, the validation from the DatePicker is executed. After the validation, neither the KeyDown nor the KeyBinding command is executed.

I suspect that the DatePicker-TextBox sets 'Handled' to true.

Is there any way that I can access the validation function from the DatePicker?

```
 <Window.InputBindings>
     <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding EnterCommand}" />
 </Window.InputBindings>

 <Grid>
     <StackPanel>
         <DatePicker
             KeyDown="DatePicker_KeyDown"
             PreviewKeyDown="DatePicker_PreviewKeyDown" />

         <TextBox Height="20" />
     </StackPanel>
 </Grid>
```

[WPF datagrid with datepicker in cell blocks the enter key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39066459/wpf-datagrid-with-datepicker-in-cell-blocks-the-enter-key)

With this CustomDatePicker I can change Handled to false.

But it would be better if the first Enter press starts the validation and sets 'Handled' to true, and a second Enter press would start the KeyBinding event.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to invoke the `EnterCommand` whenever the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key is pressed regardless of which control that currently has the focus and how this control is implemented, you should handle the `PreviewKeyDown` event instead of using a `KeyBinding`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        PreviewKeyDown += (s, e) =>
        {
            dynamic viewModel = DataContext; //..or cast to your type
            viewModel.EnterCommand.Execute(null);
        };

        ...
        }
    }
}
```

This is exactly as MVVM compliant as your current solution of using a `KeyBinding` but it works better (depending on your requirements).

Comment: Thanks for your response! But I don't want to always handle the Enter command. I have another control where I want to handle the Enter key without triggering the command.